# IOS, No output when AUGraphConnectNodeInput is set

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, augraph

I am stuck with AUGraph for a while now and would really appreciate if my problem is resolved.
What is am trying to do right now is to play data(bytes) coming from UDP. I have successfully achieved how to play data using AUGraph but i can't figure out how to change its playback speed.

My current scenario is to get Data from UDP, pass it a converter -> newTimePitch -> converter -> ioUnit.

**Converters:** Converters, convert ASBD of 48000 to desired format for timePitch and again convert it back to 48000 to play from ioUnit.

**IOUnit** Currently for demonstration i have removed the UDP and played revert back by using 2 different ioUnit (One for recording and other for playing).

**CircularBuffer** In Recording callback i am pushing data into my circular buffer and in playback Callback i am poping data from it and *memcpy* to my *ioData*

Don't be overwhelmed by the code you see. Its simple.

Starting AUGraph and Recording AudioUnit.

```
private func startRecordingUnit() 
{
    check(error: AUGraphStart(graph!), description: "Failed to start AUGraph")
    check(error: AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit!), description: "Failed to start recording
        audio unit.")
}
```

### Setup AUGraph

```
private func setupRecordingUnit(){

    var description = AudioComponentDescription(
        componentType: OSType(kAudioUnitType_Output),
        componentSubType: OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO),
        componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
        componentFlags: 0,
        componentFlagsMask: 0
    )

    let inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(nil, &description)
    check(error: AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent!, &audioUnit), description: 
    "Failed to init recording audio unit.")

    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(
        audioUnit!,
        AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO),
        AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Input),
        kInputBus,
        &flag,
        MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(flag)
        ),
          description: "Failed to set enable IO for recording."
    )

    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(
        audioUnit!,
        AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat),
        AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Output),
        kInputBus,
        &ioFormat!,
        MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(ioFormat)
        ),
          description: "Failed to set stream format on output unit with scope input."
    )

    check(error: NewAUGraph(&graph), description: "Failed to create AU Graph")

    check(error: AUGraphOpen(graph!), description: "Failed to open AUGraph")

    var outputDesc = AudioComponentDescription(
        componentType: OSType(kAudioUnitType_Output),
        componentSubType: OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO),
        componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
        componentFlags: 0,
        componentFlagsMask: 0
    )

    var firstConverterDesc = AudioComponentDescription(
        componentType: OSType(kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter),
        componentSubType: OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_AUConverter),
        componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
        componentFlags: 0,
        componentFlagsMask: 0
    )

    var pitchConverterDesc = AudioComponentDescription(
        componentType: OSType(kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter),
        componentSubType: OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch),
        componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
        componentFlags: 0,
        componentFlagsMask: 0
    )

    var secondConverterDesc = AudioComponentDescription(
        componentType: OSType(kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter),
        componentSubType: OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_AUConverter),
        componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
        componentFlags: 0,
        componentFlagsMask: 0
    )

    check(error: AUGraphAddNode(graph!, &firstConverterDesc, &firstConverterNode), 
    description: "Failed to Add Node of First desc")
    check(error: AUGraphAddNode(graph!, &pitchConverterDesc, &newTimePitchNode), 
    description: "Failed to Add Node of new Time Desc")
    check(error: AUGraphAddNode(graph!, &secondConverterDesc, &secondConverterNode), 
    description: "Failed to Add Node of Second desc")
    check(error: AUGraphAddNode(graph!, &outputDesc, &outputNode), description: "Failed to 
    add node of output desc")

    check(error: AUGraphNodeInfo(graph!, firstConverterNode, nil, &firstConverterUnit), 
    description: "Failed to get Node Info of FIRST Unit")
    check(error: AUGraphNodeInfo(graph!, newTimePitchNode, nil, &newTimePitchUnit), 
    description: "Failed to get Node Info of new Time Unit")
    check(error: AUGraphNodeInfo(graph!, secondConverterNode, nil, &secondConverterUnit), 
    description: "Failed to get Node Info of SECOND Unit")
    check(error: AUGraphNodeInfo(graph!, outputNode, nil, &outputUnit), description: "Failed 
    to get Node Info of output Unit");

    var sizeASBD = MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(AudioStreamBasicDescription())
    var ioASBDin = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
    var ioASBDout = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
    AudioUnitGetProperty(newTimePitchUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &ioASBDin, &sizeASBD);
    AudioUnitGetProperty(newTimePitchUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &ioASBDout, &sizeASBD);

    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(firstConverterUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &ioFormat, MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(ioFormat)), 
    description: "Failed to set property of FIRST Unit")
    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(firstConverterUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &ioASBDin, MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(ioASBDin)), 
    description: "Failed to set property first unit to temp format")

    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(newTimePitchUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &ioASBDin, MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(ioASBDin)), 
    description: "Failed to set property of new Time Pitch")
    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(newTimePitchUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &ioASBDout, MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(ioASBDout)), 
    description: "Failed to set property of new Time Pitch OUTOUT")

    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(secondConverterUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &ioASBDout, MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(ioASBDout)), 
    description: "Failed to set property of Second Converter Unit")
    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(secondConverterUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &ioFormat, MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(ioFormat)), 
    description: "Failed to set property of Second Converter Unit to io Format")

    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(outputUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &ioFormat, MemoryLayoutStride.SizeOf32(ioFormat)), 
    description: "Failed to set property of OUTPUT Unit")

    // ************************************* RECORDING 
    ****************************************************

    var recordingCallback = AURenderCallbackStruct(
        inputProc: AudioController_RecordingCallback,
        inputProcRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
    )

    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(
        audioUnit!,
        AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback),
        AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Global),
        kInputBus,
        &recordingCallback,
        MemoryLayout<AURenderCallbackStruct>.size.ui
        ),
          description: "Failed to set property on recording callback."
    )
    // *************************************** RECORDING END 
    ****************************************************

    var playbackCallback = AURenderCallbackStruct(
        inputProc: AudioController_PlaybackCallback,
        inputProcRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
    )

    check(error: AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph!, firstConverterNode, 0, newTimePitchNode, 
    0), description: "Failed to connect FIRST AND timePitch Nodes")
    check(error: AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph!, newTimePitchNode, 0, secondConverterNode, 
    0), description: "Failed to connect timePitch AND Second Nodes")
    check(error: AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph!, secondConverterNode, 0, outputNode, 0), 
    description: "Failed to connect Second AND OUTPUT Nodes")

    check(error: AudioUnitSetProperty(outputUnit!, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &playbackCallback, 
    MemoryLayout<AURenderCallbackStruct>.size.ui), description: "Failed to set Property for 
    varispeed Unit 1")

        check(error: AUGraphInitialize(graph!), description: "Unable to initialize AUGraph")

}
```

---

### Recording is working fine but playbackCalback doesn't run after I connect it with `AUConvertor`.

For testing purposes I removed connections `AUGraphConnectNodeInput` and it started playing. I think something is wrong with connections and I would really appreciate if I understand what is causing the problem.

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313967/dave234
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41774145
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872368
- [Connection of varispeed with RemoteIO in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651259/connection-of-varispeed-with-remoteio-in-ios)

I have made couple of searches but can't find any useful help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that you are setting two inputs to your IO node (remote or voice processing), and no inputs to your audio graph.

Comment: i know, but scenario as i described above is: we are sending and getting data from UDP. To replicate this i have created 2 IOUnits, one is recording and other is playing, IF i don't use the AUGraphConnectNodeInput i am able to record and play data using these 2 IOUnits,

Comment: Draw a picture of your graph (directed graph with arrows including IO and callbacks) and you will see your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the issue and you are right that i am not inputting anything into my AUGraph. But i am still stuck in a scenario where i am getting data from UDP.
UDP -> Converter -> Varispeed -> output
Please help me with connecting UDP data to my converter node. i have completed and tested my code with revertback and it worked fine but not with UDP.

Comment: I am confused on how to connect my UDP incoming data to my converter